# After generating Word Document, the word did not die and keep using my memories

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a little problem on my projects.
My project is a mvc, do the following jobs.
Using chrome to input data on forms, which then post to my controller
to generate word document using dynamic datas input by replacing the word
document templates.

It finished this part perfectly by replacing the bookmarks,however, the
only thing that border me is that after generating the word document,even
i did not open the word that i generated,there is a word running in the background, and it keep starting a new one after generating new document.

then after multiple generation, the computer becomes slow and i need to go to task manager to kill it one by one in order to release my memories again.

What are the problems? and how do i solve it?

Comment: What library are you using to generate the word documents?  If you are using interop to talk to a locally installed instance of Word, this is not supported and you will have a lot of trouble with it.

Comment: _..."the word did not die and keep using my memories"_ sounds like a line from a movie. :D

Comment: Sorry for the unclear discription, i am using interop to a locally installed instance of Word, also Excel tbh.... After looking at your comment,i did search and that seems a big trouble. any short cut method?

Comment: There are plenty of libraries out there that will allow you to programmatically create a word document, via ASP.Net, without having Word installed locally.  A quick google search is all you need.

Comment: The worst case is i have already done like ten of thousands of codes already, generating 100+ word or excel documents, i may not be able to make it happen if i now search for alternatives...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive my stupidity

Just simply add :

```
winApp.Quit()
```

and everything is done.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: 
`Dim pProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Word")
            For Each p As Process In pProcess
                p.Kill()
            Next`